# Display contents of PHP variable after Joomla RSForm submission

Tags: php, joomla

I have created a RSForm in Joomla which uses cURL to connect to an API and create a ticket on a third party system.

After the form is submitted, a ticket number is generated and stored in a variable `$ticket`. This variable is in the "Script called after form has been processed" section of the form.

I need to display the value of this variable along with a thank you message after form submission.

Something like "Thank you for you submission. Your ticket number is :......"

Answer (score 1):

This is documented in the [Getting Started/PHP Scripts](https://www.rsjoomla.com/support/documentation/rsform-pro/getting-started/php-scripts.html) section of the documentation.

You just need to modify `$thankYouMessage`, like:

```
$thankYouMessage .= "Your ticket number is: $ticket"
```

Comment: Perfect, that worked like a charm! Thank a lot Grisha, appreciated.